# Sublime Text 2: Keyboard shortcut to comment no longer works

Tags: css, sublimetext2, package-control

I recently installed y0ssar1an's excellent CSS3 Syntax package in Sublime Text 2, and I can no longer use the command+foward_slash combo to toggle comments. Toggling comments still works in non-CSS files.

I checked the default preferences, and the shortcut still seems to be there:

`{ "keys": ["super+forward_slash"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } }`

There's nothing in the user preferences to override this. How can I troubleshoot further?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in the `CSS3_Syntax` package that would disable or change comments. Did you install any other plugins recently?

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo. No, I haven't installed any other plugins, and this issue happened immediately after installing CSS3 Syntax. Only comments in CSS files seem to be affected, all other files comments toggle normally. I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you add `"CSS"` to the `"ignored_packages"` array in your user preferences?

Comment: I use BoundKeys plugin to help troubleshooting issues regarding key bindings.